# Create Model of Schema Mongoose (Node.js) for simplify the code

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, schema

I checked the previous examples but couldn't find any ideas.
Programming means don't repeat yourself, and I want create a model , but I didn't understand how to do it, I would like to apply it to the example below. thanks

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  
const fasiSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    controlloMateriale : {
        tempoaSchedaInOre: {  type: Date, required: false  },
        tempoTotaleInOre: {  type: Date, required: false }       
    },
    equipaggiamento : {
        tempoaSchedaInOre: {  type: Date, required: false  },
        tempoTotaleInOre: {  type: Date, required: false }
    },
});

mongoose.model('fasi',fasiSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward. Just create a const with the common schema value and use that where value is repeated

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');  

const DateSchema = {  type: Date, required: false };
const CustomSchema = {
            tempoaSchedaInOre: DateSchema,
            tempoTotaleInOre: DateSchema  };

const fasiSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        controlloMateriale : CustomSchema,
        equipaggiamento : CustomSchema,
    });

mongoose.model('fasi',fasiSchema);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought I was using specific models, but in reality this is the best solution. Thanks also for the meticulousness of the details

Comment: If I wanted to insert "fasiSchema" properties in an array, how could overcome the problem of the empty mongoose array? Because I’ve done several tests like this but there’s nothing to do: const fasiSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    
        fase: {                 
                type:[{   
        controlloMaterialeSmd : CustomSchema,
        equipaggiamentoSerig : CustomSchema
        
       
        }]
        }

Answer (score 0):

In cases such as that there is no alternative. You simply have to repeat yourself. You could create a system with templates and such but it probably wouldn't help much